# Is there any easy and cost effective way to build inhouse water treatment facility

Tags: water, water-damage, recycling, reuse, water-treatment

My apartment produces approx 1800 litre of grey water per day.

So I'm thinking may be I could build my own ( DIY ) water treatment facility which will remove the dirt and remove the smell so that I can use this water for toilet flushing atleast.

Any cool ideas on how I can do this.

My idea is

I will build a Concrete water storage pit in ground and I will have overhead plastic overtank at terrace and water pump to push to water overhead.

I will have two stage water purifying filters which will remove all the dirt particles and I will drop some bad smell remove( I don't know if anything exists).

I'm not sure if this is right one and will work quite effectively. Please advise

Comment: So you say "in house" but then say "sump in ground". So you have an earth floor in the basement? Or you have a garden where there is space for more equipment?

Comment: I have a space like 4(Width) and  60(length) outside of my building. That's where I think I can build underground water storage unit(Sump) pardon my english.

Comment: "cost effective" depends a **lot** on the relative costs. Typical municipal water is not terribly expensive, but in some places (including country or region may help) it is more expensive than others. Alternatively, well water is not expensive until you run out of capacity and have to build a new/bigger/deeper well. In some cases, cutting usage (1800 liters/day sounds like a lot, but depends on the number of people) may be a more cost-effective way to cut down total input water requirements (e.g., low-flow showers, high-efficiency washing machine, etc.)

Comment: Will also need a completely separate water lines just to toilets,etc, apart from any drinking water lines.  American lawyers would like you.

Comment: Look up the term "reclaimed water" if you want an idea of what's involved here

Comment: Step one is to figure out if the Local Authority Having Jurisdiction permits greywater reclamation at all. Some do not. Many that do have specific requirements and regulations you need to meet. Many Permaculture resources have ideas about processing greywater through a biofilter/reed bed type of setup, which is one approach to make it suitable for irrigation uses - if and only if your LAHJ approves, or you are so far out in the boonies that you don't have an LAHJ for this stuff (which is fairly unusual.) Depending on method you may only be able to do it part of the year.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - I have reduced the input but with low-flow water taps , showers etc.. but just trying to find an economical approach .. like simple aeration motor and cloth filter or something like that

Comment: @Ecnerwal - There's no jurisdiction issue but bio filter is pretty interesting . .is it like simple sediment filter kind of set up which needs changing once in a year.. seems pretty interesting

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - As far as my research goes so far all the reclaimed water approaches requires space and not so economical industrial approach

Comment: @crip659 - separate lines are there for inlet and outlet.. all the bathroom outlets are connected in one line and kitchen outlets are connected in one line.. so recycling filters are also can be attached appropriately

Comment: @SolarMike - I have space for equipment and can safely discharge the water to a sump in the ground for re-use.

Comment: With grey water it cannot be used on any supply lines that people may drink from, so no kitchen or bathroom sinks and probably bathtubs/showers, only toilets(and that is iffy).  Will need separate lines to toilets and a line for sinks.  And never have the two meet/connect.  The drainage lines from the toilets and the drainage lines from the sinks also need separation.

Comment: @crip659 - That's how its done now. I am just thinking how to purify the lines for bathroom and kitchen so water won't be so bad